# How does SNMP polling works

Tags: snmp

My guess is:

1. Use WALK to retrieve all variables (periodically)
2. Set our own rules in MIB to check for variable values:

   - true / false
   - Above certain threshold
   - etc.

I do not think the above is true.

Because if that is the case, the setup and configuration of the MIB will be tedious and user must have extensive knowledge of each variables sent by the Agent.

Hopefully someone can tell me a simpler way.

Comment: What really matters is what you are trying to monitor. For network devices, there are tons of commercial/open source monitoring tools that wrap over SNMP [like this](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-snmp-with-datadog/). For other kinds of devices, similar tools exist for decades.